# Swift accessing key from dictionary returning null

Tags: swift, dictionary, option-type

I have a dictionary. When I try to access that dictionary, it is returning a null value when it should definately be returning an actual value. I'm stumped. Any help is always appreciated.

```
if let d = response.result.value {
    print(d) //prints correct data
    let prices = d["prices"] as? [[String:AnyObject?]]
    print(prices) //prints nil
    let best_price = prices?[0]
    let price = best_price?["price"] as? String
    print(price) //prints nil
}
```

Console:

```
{
    item =     {
        "item_number" = 57;
        image = "http://example.com/tent.jpg";
        name = "Small Red Tent";
    };
    prices =     (
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=19";
        price = "58.15";
        rating = "3.64";
        "vendor_id" = 50;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=50";
        price = "58.14";
        rating = "5.00";
        "vendor_id" = 110;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=26";
        price = "50.40";
        rating = "4.71";
        "vendor_id" = 73;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=12";
        price = "47.16";
        rating = "4.00";
        "vendor_id" = 1;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=13";
        price = "45.75";
        rating = "3.90";
        "vendor_id" = 25;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=16";
        price = "41.32";
        rating = "3.02";
        "vendor_id" = 16;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=1";
        price = "36.59";
        rating = "4.84";
        "vendor_id" = 51;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=2";
        price = "36.29";
        rating = "3.26";
        "vendor_id" = 43;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=13";
        price = "34.59";
        rating = "4.14";
        "vendor_id" = 48;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=3";
        price = "32.00";
        rating = "4.29";
        "vendor_id" = 53;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=4";
        price = "24.50";
        rating = "4.16";
        "vendor_id" = 8;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=5";
        price = "15.00";
        rating = "4.87";
        "vendor_id" = 39;
    },
            {
        link = "http://example.com/id=6";
        price = "0.00";
        rating = "3.00";
        "vendor_id" = 65;
    }
);
}
nil
nil
```

[image: Screenshot showing the d dictionary]

Comment: `d["prices"] as? [AnyObject]` works? Could one of the values in it be a different object?

Comment: Can it be possible that there might be a key of type other than `String` in `prices`? Could you please dump entire `prices` array here?

Comment: `let prices = d["prices"] as? [AnyObject]` worked. So I guess the question is why wouldn't my initial code work? My keys are `String`s aren't they?

Comment: I've updated the `prices array` in the question, there was only one more field that I cut out. All the elements in the array have that same form.

Comment: Please put entire `prices` array here. No `...`.

Comment: To read a dictionary `[String:AnyObject?]` is silly because there can't be any optional value in the dictionary. Remove the question mark.

Comment: If you just use `let prices = d["prices"]` (no coercion), what datatype does Xcode think `prices` is?

Comment: It says it's an `Optional<AnyObject>`

Comment: I had some issues while trying to use `[[String:AnyObject]]`, they were connected with some strange behavior of `NSCoding`: when it decoded array of this type - it actually returned multiple copies of it. Perhaps it is some compiler problem with such type. But it's only my guess.

Comment: `as? [[String:AnyObject]]` should work. *As vadian already told, don't declare the dictionary value as an Optional.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was proposed by Larme solved the problem.

```
let prices = d["prices"] as? [AnyObject]
```

Although I never figured out why casting `d["prices"] as? [[String:AnyObject?]]` wouldn't also work.